# Ice Cream Sandwich build-in FIND feature does not highlight text in WebView

Tags: webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, textselection

To reproduce the problem do following steps in any Ice Cream Sandwich Android device:

1. Create simple app with the only activity. Put `WebView` into activity layout and load any page inside `WebView`.
2. Hold touch over text inside WebView until top "context" panel appears. Press "Find".
3. You will NOT see highlighting inside `WebView`.

Do the same with any other app, which is NOT using WebView or with browser app and highlighting will appear correctly.

Comment: hey Mike did you get the answer of this question ???

Comment: I believe no, unfortunately... just keep it alone for this platform for now.. ((